# Installing Ubuntu 12.04 on a USB stick

Tags: 12.04, installation, usb

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I install Ubuntu to a USB key?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/16988/how-do-i-install-ubuntu-to-a-usb-key)

I have a company laptop that I am allowed to use for personal things. I want to run Ubuntu on it, but I'd rather not mess with the existing partitions or boot setup.

I have bought a Kingston DataTraveler HyperX 128GB USB stick with the goal of running a full Ubuntu installation from this stick. Not a live CD, not a live CD with persistance, an actual real full installation.

Should I just go ahead running the Ubuntu installer from CD and installing to my USB stick as if it were a hard disk? Can I just write a bootloader to the USB stick and boot from the stick through the BIOS boot menu?

Are there other things I should remember to take care of? I am planning to run tmp from a tmpfs ramdisk to ease down on the writes (is this still an issue with modern USB sticks?) I am not sure what I will do with the swap partition yet - the system has 4GB of RAM so I'm considering running without a swap partition.

I welcome your input and I hope this question was not posted in the wrong place.